# In AngularJS, how can I see errors from templates, such as calls to undefined methods?

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

If I have an AngularJS template that looks something like:

```
{{foo.someFunc()}}
```

And nothing is rendered, it is hard to tell what the problem was:

- Was `foo` undefined?
- Was `foo.someFunc` undefined?
- Was the function defined, but returning an empty string?
- Or was it perhaps encountering an error?

In the cases where there *is* an error (like `foo` or `someFnc` not being defined), no error is reported to me.

Is there a way to change that?

Comment: We need to see more code to know what the problem is. Please paste the HTML & JS.

Comment: @CaseyFlynn I mean this super generally. Seems like templating is swallowing errors — I’d like visibility.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS expressions are not evaluated with eval().

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

This is actually a huge advantage of Angular, as it leads to less buggy user experiences.

> Forgiving: expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null, unlike in JavaScript, where trying to evaluate undefined properties can generate ReferenceError or TypeError.

As far as I know, there is no way to change this ^

Answer (score 0):

I think about this in a different way.
When you write a template you are **not writing executable code**, you are **describing** what the layout/functionality should be.

If having undefined objects is considered a bug then you need to look in the **controller** that's exposing that object to the scope. **Tests** should tell if a function or controller is behaving correctly not the template.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but you still write expressions in layouts. And there will be bugs.

Comment: Ok, but I would consider the controller's job to supply the correct values for the expression references. So if the objects are not correct it's up to the controller to make sure they are and that's where tests come in. The view is there for the end user not the developer.